# Assembly Language: Where to place .txt file so that the program can read it? (DOSBox)

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox, emu8086

I need to read and display a text file for an assignment. Basically, it needs to read and display the text in the file called "textfile.txt". In EMU8086, I know where to place the file and the program runs fine. However, in DOSBox, I do not know where to place the "textfile.txt".

When I run this program, it doesn't do anything

```
.model small
org 100h  
.data
.code
org 100h ;.com memory layout
;****FOR EMU8086: PLACE THE FILE named "textfile.txt" IN C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C***
mov dx, offset file 
mov al,0 
mov ah,3dh
int 21h 
jc terminate
mov bx,ax

mov cx, 99 
mov dx, offset buf
mov ah, 3fh 
int 21h
JZ terminate 


MOV SI, offset buf 
print:
mov al, [SI]
mov ah,0eh 
int 10h
INC SI
CMP BYTE PTR [SI], 0  ;CMP [SI], 0
JNE print 


terminate:

;mov ah, 0 
;int 16h

ret


file db "C:\TASM\textfile.txt",0 ;****PLACE THE FILE IN C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C***
buf db 99 dup(0)
counter db 0



end
```

When I use the EMU8086, I placed the .txt file in the `C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C` directory. In the code above, I placed the .txt file in `C:\TASM` directory and it doesn't work. Wanted to note that this code is also in `C:\TASM`. Where should I place the .txt file for the program to work in DOSBox?

Comment: have you tried the working directory?

Comment: The code and the .txt file are in the same directory

Comment: Try writing a program that *creates* a file with a DOS system call, and see where it ends up when you use a relative or absolute path.  Although it should probably be the same as if you `echo foo > c:\TASM\test.txt` on the DOS command line inside DOSBOX, so try that first as a quick test.

Comment: its where you start the program, not where your source code is, however, you seem to have an absolute path, so it should work regardless of where you start. You should try placing it in the root of c, and change file to be "C:\textfile.txt"

Comment: ok i did that. i wrote a "make a new text file" code and ran it with dosbox and it made the new file in TASM. I dont get this. This project is due in a few hours so need help asap guys

Comment: as long as you have the path, putting the file anywhere will do

Comment: esoterik, same issue. when i run it in dosbox, i get a black line with a blinking cursor. when i type two lines. it exists. i dont get it

Comment: you declared the path as `C:\TASM\textfile.txt` so obviously you must put it in `C:\TASM`. Or just give `textfile.txt` and put the file in the current working directory

Comment: Guys i did everything u guys said and its not working. this is due in 1 hour. please help. i tried everything

Comment: How did you compile/link the program? Did you link it to a `.COM` or `.EXE`?

Comment: i did it in .com

Comment: Did you compile it with TASM? If so, you should change *.model* to tiny, remove *.data*, define a `start:` label before `mov dx, offset file` and change the last line to `end start` to define the entry point for the link

Comment: What folder of the host OS did you mount as C: in dosbox? Did you place the exe/com and the txt files there?

Comment: Did you try debugging your program (with a debugger) so you could single-step?  Have you *confirmed* that the open-file system call is returning an error?  Maybe there's just a bug in the rest of your program.

Comment: `terminate: ret' will not work, you should call int 21/4c to return to dos

Comment: @Tommylee2k It does work AFAIK as DOS pushes a pointer to an `int 0x20` instruction on the stack before starting your program.

Comment: `JZ terminate` should be `JC terminate`, the dos API sets carry on error, not zero flag

Comment: @fuz still one should use int `21/4c`, if the programs should ever run elsewhere than in dosbox

Comment: @Tommylee2k No.  The same thing happens on real DOS.

Comment: @fuz and this is guaranteed to work on all DOSes? Don't get used to bad habits, this may fall back onto you e.g. when developing for "real" OSs which will not accept just `ret`. I'm sure there is a reason why 21/4c exists

Comment: @Tommylee2k Yes, it is guaranteed to work on all DOS implementations because it's part of MS-DOS 1 and many programs use this.  I think it dates back to CP/M, but I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: @Tommylee2k the `ret` is "guaranteed" to work on any DOS for COM files (although I bet there ever existed some DOS being incompatible). For EXE files `4Ch` is definitely safer, or `int 20h`. I don't recall `ret` in EXE should work.

Answer (score 2):

DOSBox doesn't know the drive `C:` by default. You can mount it to any physical path. Enter at DOSBox prompt:

```
mount C C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C
```

Now, the file is at the same location for EMU8086 and DOSBox. To find TASM I recommend:

```
mount T C:\TASM
path T:\BIN;
```

To find EMU8086 and via `PATH` the compiled code:

```
mount E C:\EMU80856
path E:\MyBuild;
```

DOSBox finds the source code in E:\MySource.

You can automatize these steps with the [dosbox-0.74.conf](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf). Load it in a text editor and move to the section `[autoexec]`. Insert the lines above:

```
...
[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.

path T:\BIN;E:\MyBuild
mount C C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C
mount E C:\EMU8086
mount T C:\TASM
...
```

These commands will be executed at every start of DOSBox.

Your code will not work with TASM. This one will work:

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h
start:

mov dx, offset file
mov al,0
mov ah,3dh
int 21h
jc terminate
mov bx,ax

mov cx, 99
mov dx, offset buf
mov ah, 3fh
int 21h
JZ terminate


MOV SI, offset buf
print:
mov al, [SI]
mov ah,0eh
int 10h
INC SI
CMP BYTE PTR [SI], 0  ;CMP [SI], 0
JNE print

terminate:

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h

file db "C:\textfile.txt",0 ;****PLACE THE FILE IN C:\EMU8086\vdrive\C***
buf db 99 dup(0)
counter db 0

end start
```

Build it with

```
e:
cd \mysource
tasm mycode.asm
tlink /t mycode.obj
```